# How to customize third-party package in django

Tags: django

I couldn't find anywhere an explicit guide that will show what is the correct way. For example, I am using a package django-two-factor-auth for my django website. I wanted to add a context variable to the template and display it. I created a folder two_factor inside of my templates folder and the template file with the same name. That part is easy. But I also needed to inherit generic view to add my context (of course, I don't want to change source code of the third-party package). For this I created a new app inside my project and called it two_factor_custom and added following code to views.py:

```
from binascii import unhexlify
from base64 import b32encode
from two_factor.views.core import SetupView

class SetupViewCustom(SetupView):
  def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
     context = super(SetupViewCustom, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)
     if self.steps.current == 'generator':
        key = unhexlify(self.get_key('generator').encode('ascii'))
        context.update({
           'secret': b32encode(key).decode('ascii')
        })
     return context
```

I would appreciate if you could say that this is the correct way to extend or override some of the behaviour of third-party packages. If not what I am doing wrong?

Comment: there is no "correct" way to extend apps, extending a class and overriding a method is excellent approach..

Comment: Why do you think this is the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the template context by adding your own template context processor. See also the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).

> The TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting is a tuple of callables – called context processors – that take a request object as their argument and return a dictionary of items to be merged into the context.